# Transforming a circle to get a parabola

Tags: transformation, computational-geometry, projective-geometry

On http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html

I am unable to understand the following point

> Obviously, this transformation sends $\;(x,y,w)=(1,0,1)\;$ to $\;(x',y',w') =
> > (1,-1,0).\;$ That is, this projective transformation sends $\;(1,0)\;$ on the
>   $xy-$plane to the point at infinity in direction $\;<1,-1>.\;$ From the
>   right-hand side of the matrix equation $\;x=Px'\;$ we have
>
> ```
> x = 2x' + y'
> y = x' + y'                                               (1)
> w = 2x' + y' + w'
> ```
>
> Let us consider a circle $\;x^2 + y^2 = 1.\;$ Plugging the above equations
>   into the circle equation changes it to the following:
>
> ```
> x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - 4xw - 2yw - w^2 = 0                     (2)
> ```
>
> Dividing the above by $\;w^2\;$ to convert it back to conventional form
>   yields
>
> ```
> x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - 4x - 2y - 1 = 0                         (3)
> ```
>
> This is a parabola! (Why?) Therefore, a circle that has no point at
>   infinity is transformed to a parabola that does have point at
>   infinity.

How is (2) the equation of a circle. I tried converting to homogenous coordinates, applying the transformation, and then comparing and I can't get the same answer.

How is (3) a parabola? It has an $\;x^2\;$ term and a $\;y^2\;$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is $(x+y)^2-4x-2y-1=0$ so will be a parabola with an opening parallel to $x=-y$  Continuing, we have $$(x+y)^2-4x-2y-1=0\\(x+y)^2-3(x+y)+\frac 94+(y-x)-\frac{13}4=0\\(x+y-\frac 32)^2=-(y-x)+\frac{13}4$$ so you have a parabola rotated by $\frac \pi 4$